# WebSphere 7 using one node of cluster by wsadmin

Tags: websphere, wsadmin

I want to do postdeploy script to add only one properties file to application war. I know that I can add it by AdminApp.update and it works on one node server.

Is it possible to do this on cluster? I mean, that I want run AdminApp.update script for each server and for each node in cluster with different properties.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In a WebSphere cluster, each member receives the exact same application binaries. If you use `AdminApp.update` to modify a property file in the application, then that change will be pushed to all cluster members.

Comment: it's about property file in war. if i will change it in <profile>/installedApps/my.ear/my.war will it automatically synchronize to all servers? i just want to specify some cross definitions between 2 servers.

Comment: No, installedApps is where WebSphere extracts the application binaries. Changes to these files will not be propagated, but they will be overwritten when changes are made to the application in the configuration repository (which is what AdminApp.update does).